# Prevent vscode automatic add two space after enter in python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am writing python code in vscode, after an expression, each time I hit enter to start a new line, it will automatic add one space for the newline.

Instead, what I really want is the starting new line would be aligned with the start of the statement, i.e:

```
def fun():
    arg = 'fake'
    cursor should be aligned with arg
```

Now what I got is the cursor is one space of the start. I searched and couldn't find out where to set this, the Tab Size is 4 space.

I still don't find out the causing issue, but on my project I solved it by setting black path to my absolute path. The answers provided below is not the reason why it doesn't work in my vscode. I attached the pic here.[My vscode shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wcEI.png)

Comment: I have this issue, and nothing seems to work. And to all the answers. I have set the indent correctly. Pressing TAB results in the desired behavior. Just Pressing enter when it is already indented is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

the problem was 'python indent' extension that I installed. I deleted and it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33877575)

Comment: Sweet! I tried all solutions and only this one worked after spending so much time.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type in `Indent with spaces`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `4`.

Comment: U mean Indent Using space, but it's not working, I already set it to 4, I think it's becasue of something else?  I solved this problem by setting my black path, but I guess the problem is caused by some other setting, I am very confused anyway

Comment: Make sure you have `Spaces: 4` in the bottm-right corner of the screen.

Comment: yes, I am sure, but this doesn't solve my problem, that's why I am confused

Comment: Do you have Pylance activated ? I just got an indentation issue, which was cause by Pylance

Comment: yes, I have pylance activated, so pylance could cause this problem?  Anyway it can be solved by: setting python.formatting.provider to black to solve it, in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Set also the tab size at the status bar to 4 instead of 2 and you're good to go.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your situation for now:

[image]

Click `Space:2` and select `Indent Using Space`:

[image]

Slect 4:

[image]

It should be work:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explaination, but that's not my probelm, I've tried setting and pretty sure that the tab size is 4, I attached my pic and explained that I solved it by setting black path, but i don't know the true reason causing it

Comment: @Allen Huang It looks like the formatting affects it. Could you try to switch the "python.formatting.provider" to others? And could you take the space as the indent instead of tab?